# Image not appearing in views

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, image, model-view-controller

I have a syntax error for my image tag in my Ruby on Rails application:

```
<%= image_tag('smiley.png'), :class =>"img-responsive", :style => "height:90%; width:60%;" %>
```

It says "unexpected keyword" and "expecting end-of-input". Can anybody tell me what is wrong with the syntax?

Comment: When asking about an error, put the exact error message into your question. Don't paraphrase it and don't remove detail such as the line-number of the error. Read "[mcve]".

Comment: It's best if you set the image size in any class, too.

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html#method-i-image_tag):

```
<%= image_tag('smiley.png', class: 'img-responsive', style: 'height:90%; width:60%;') %>
```

--

*Rich Peck edit...*

This is basic [argument assignment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parameter_(computer_programming)#Example) in programming.

When you call a function, you have the ability to pass data to it as *arguments*. These arguments represent [local variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_variable), which you can use within the function / subroutine.

Since [`image_tag`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html#method-i-image_tag) is such a function which accepts arguments, your problem is that you've closed the brackets, preventing the arguments from being passed.

You just need to include the `class` & `style` options inside the function's brackets for them to be passed as valid arguments. You may also benefit from knowing that [Ruby doesn't need brackets](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide):

```
<%= image_tag "smiley.png", class: "img-responsive", style: "height: 90%; width: 60%;" %>
```